# How to set the position of a sprite to the position of another sprite?

Tags: c#, xna

Is it possible to set the position of a sprite to the exact same position of another sprite which is being moved.

So I want to set the "sprite.position" to a the same position that my class Character is in:

Character.cs:

```
    class Character
    {
        Texture2D texture;
        public Vector2 position;
        Vector2 velocity; 

        public Character(Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPosition)
        {

            texture = newTexture;
            position = newPosition;

        }
        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            position += velocity;

        }   

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
        }

    }
```

Game1.cs:

```
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {


        Bullet bullet;

        Character player;


        protected override void Initialize()
        {

            allSprites = new List<ISprite>();
            allSpriteObstakels = new List<ISprite>();

            bullet.position = Character.position; // not working




            base.Initialize();
        }

      }
```

Comment: Of course its possible. What about your approach are you having trouble with?

Comment: In my Game1.cs I tried to call "bullet.position = Character.position;" but this ain't working

Comment: And what isn't working about that? Is the assignment failing? "It doesn't work" **is not a problem statement**. Pro tip: Don't have one line with a "not working" comment in a giant wall of code with nothing else. *No one will ever see it*. Make an MCVE and call out *exactly* what isn't working *in the body of the question itself*.

Comment: I tried to minimize it, I hope I didn't minimize it too much

Comment: You still haven't said *what* isn't working. What about that line is broken? It looks like valid C#. Do you get a compile error, runtime exception, velociraptors attack when you run it, what? (Now that I see it, just change to `player.Position` its not a static property, still I could have seen it faster if you had *given the error*).

Comment: Okay, now I got it tells me: "NullReference was unhandled" on the same line

Comment: Well, you *do* need to instantiate a player before you can set something to its position...

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work, I will just give up. Thank you for helping me anyways :)

Comment: Piece of advice: Try to learn some programming concepts (like instantiation, assignment, etc.) in a simpler context. This is *really easy* to do if you know what you are doing. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, im going to read some indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have suggested, when you say "it's not working" you need to be clear about what "not working" actually means.  For example, are you getting a compile error?  Are you getting a runtime exception?  Is the game running but it isn't doing what you expect (logical error)?

That said, here's my best guess as to what might be going on:

- I don't know if the code above is complete but the bullet and player are not instantiated anywhere.  You need to "new" the instances before you use them.
- You are using the "bullet.position" where bullet is an instance, but then you're using "Character.position" where Character is a class.  Did you intend to use "player.position" instead?
- This code will only run once, which means the bullet will be set to the same position as the character.  If you intend for the bullet position to always be the same as the character, then you need to continually re-assign the bullet.position value every frame.

But the most important thing is to learn to ask questions so that the community here can help you out.